# What is this leafy plant with thick stems and carrot-like leaves?

Tags: identification

[image]This is a volunteer.  Not sure what it is.  Can you tell me?  I would pull it if it's a weed but not sure. In Omaha, NE in the mostly sun partial shade.  I had two pop up one is by the driveway the other close to the house.  Just regular dirt with mulch. The leaves remind me of carrot leaves but a little bigger.

[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). An idea of the size of the plant is also helpful if it's not evident from photographs. If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a lot like flat-leaf parsley. Or Sweet Cicely. Smelling/tasting the plant will be proof positive if it's either of those. The former tastes like,
umm, parsley, and the latter has a mild anise taste/scent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Hemlock](http://wildeherb.com/2010/07/16/poison-hemlock-prolific-in-the-fence-rows/)

[image]

Give it a chance and it'll shoot up to eight feet high, flower, then fall over and die back.

Comment: Based on the pictures I think that's not quite right. Poison Hemlock leaves are very finely divided, these pictures don't seem to be quite that segmented to me. Definitely thinking Apiaceae family though.

Comment: @GardenerJ Could be. I was figuring different levels of molybdenum in the soil, or intraspecies variation or some such. Don't know how much the stuff varies between locations, so you could well be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Smooth, purple blotched stems, leaves similar to wild carrot, could be POISON HEMLOCK. The flowers will tell for sure. Do not handle. Deadly plant.

Comment: That answer has already been given.